# SFML linker problems on eclipse VC++

Tags: visual-c++, eclipse-cdt, sfml

I am trying to use the [SFML](http://www.sfml-dev.org/) library for audio in my project.

I am developing in eclipse juno for c++ and am using SFML v1.6.

I added `sfml-audio-d.lib`, `sfml-main-d.lib`, and `sfml-system-d.lib` into

`C/C++ General > paths and symbols>libraries`

I also defined a macro named SFML_DYNAMIC into

`C/C++ Build>Settings>C++ Compiler>Preprocessor` 'Defines /D' section

I added the directory that contains all the dlls into the PATH environment variable.

In my code I make use of sf::SoundBuffer, but when I try to build the project I get the following linker error:

`Chunk.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "private: static class sf::SoundBuffer * Chunk::breakBlockSound" (?breakBlockSound@Chunk@@0PAVSoundBuffer@sf@@A)
MyProject.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had to rebuild the project in VS2010 before using it. Works now.